# JSON Conversion URL Error

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

We are trying to convert a JSON and we have some URL's in our MySQL Table as string.

We are using this code,

```
$conn = new mysqli("xxx");
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


$row_array['kategori_id'] = $row['kategori_id'];
 }



echo json_encode($json_response);
```

But we are getting url's as "http://" in output.
The slashes after http is turned upside down. / \ \ / 
Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us stored urls and parsed urls by json?

Comment: *"We are using this code, `$conn = new mysqli("xxx");`"* - Just the one parameter? Is that your actual code? *Ah, I didn't think so.* Plus, where is `$json_response` being defined?

Comment: I have added JSON response in answers. After http tag slashes are not displayed corrrectly even stackoverflow fix it, it is not like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try unescaping your urls with `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag:

`json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Answer (score 1):

This is the JSON response we are getting.

[{"kategori_id":"1","id":"1","soru_adi":"nekdar kezbans\u0131n","parent_id":"0","cevap":"cevap1","cevap2":"cevap2","cevap3":"cevap3","cevap4":"cevap4","cevap5":"cevap5","cevappuan":"5","cevappuan2":"10","cevappuan3":"15","cevappuan4":"20","cevappuan5":"2","cevapresim":"http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/126/c/","cevapresim2":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","cevapresim3":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","cevapresim4":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","cevapresim5":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonuctext":"sonuc","sonuctext2":"sonuc2","sonuctext3":"sonuc3","sonuctext4":"sonuc4","sonuctext5":"sonuc5","sonucresim":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonucresim2":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonucresim3":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonucresim4":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonucresim5":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble"},{"kategori_id":"1","id":"9","soru_adi":"\u0130kinci soru","parent_id":"0","cevap":"cevap1","cevap2":"cevap2","cevap3":"cevap3","cevap4":"cevap4","cevap5":"cevap5","cevappuan":"5","cevappuan2":"10","cevappuan3":"15","cevappuan4":"20","cevappuan5":"2","cevapresim":"http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/126/c/","cevapresim2":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","cevapresim3":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","cevapresim4":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","cevapresim5":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonuctext":"sonuc","sonuctext2":"sonuc2","sonuctext3":"sonuc3","sonuctext4":"sonuc4","sonuctext5":"sonuc5","sonucresim":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonucresim2":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonucresim3":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonucresim4":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble","sonucresim5":"http://img1.loadtr.com/b-423096-Sat\u0131l\u0131k_duble"}]

But stackoverflow doesn't allow us to see slashes after http unfixed.